# How to show hidden text in both direction

Tags: html, css

```
.hidden-text {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.div-hover-item:hover .hidden-text {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I am trying to achieve the function when cursor hover around the text , the hidden text will be show up. Here is the code, and it actually works.

Now when you move the cursor around the text, the hidden text will be show up in the top direction, but i want to change the direction to the bot so it means when you hover on the text, the hidden text will be come down, not top.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5gdr.jpg) [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gUcD.jpg) Maybe my describe is not clear, so here i will tell more details. in the pictures i upload is the hover effect work now. What i want to change is to make the container and hidden text go down of the pictures. it just like write down something under the VR photo title. but it should be out of the pictures.

Comment: add hidden text element (.hidden-text) after (.div-hover-item) in the page

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with a example? I don't understand the down and up direction, with your code the text will appear and disappear without any direction

Comment: sorry, i update more information now.

Comment: do you have any live link?

Comment: sorry. this is in the localhost, so it doesn´t have link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood, maybe you want something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: gray;
}

.hidden-text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.div-hover-item {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.div-hover-item:hover .hidden-text {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
<div class="div-hover-item">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p class="hidden-text">consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

On click with jQuery:

```js
$(".div-hover-item").click(function() {
  if ($(".hidden-text").hasClass("show")) {
    $(".hidden-text").removeClass("show");
  } else
    $(".hidden-text").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: gray;
}

.hidden-text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.div-hover-item {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.hidden-text.show {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
<div class="div-hover-item">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p class="hidden-text">consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes..this is what i mean ! sorry, my English is poor.

Comment: Do u know how to change hover to click property ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
.div-hover-item{padding:0;}
```